# cache_dir and some hardening squid

Tags: squid, hardening

Suppose i'm going to define multiple `cache_dir` such as :

```
cache_dir .....   # disk 1
cache_dir .....   # disk 2
cache_dir .....   # disk 3
```

**Question:**

Do i need to define `maximum_object_size` and `minimum_object_size` and other directives  per disk ? `cache_dir*my directives` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I know this firsthand. I also just tested it and it throws an error if those options are missing. This was on squid 3.3.8-1ubunut6.1, but should hold true for any version I've seen.